# Copying sub-folders from remote machine to remote machine directory

Tags: linux, ssh, scp

I have directory(`/usr/share/hub-bucket/GameImages/`) which has sub directories which contains files. And I want to transfer the sub-directories to machine to location `/usr/share/hub-bucket/GameImages/`. Both are remote machine, I can access remote destination using SSH private key and passphrase. And in future I will need to sync both the remote source and remote destination folder/files. How can this be implemented ?? I have used SCP for file transfer but haven't used for folder/sub-folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use scp you can use -r option, like this

```
scp  -r /usr/share/hub-bucket/GameImages/  user@remote-host:/usr/share/hub-bucket/GameImages/
```

you can also use rsync command

```
rsync -avz /usr/share/hub-bucket/GameImages/ user@remote-host:/usr/share/hub-bucket/GameImages/
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Can u give example with SSH key ??

Comment: scp  -i  /path/to/mykey.pem -r /usr/share/hub-bucket/GameImages/  user@remote-host:/usr/share/hub-bucket/GameImages/

Comment: if you use rsync you can use this command `rsync -avz --rsh="ssh -p1234  -i ~/.ssh/1234-identity" -avz /usr/share/hub-bucket/GameImages/ user@remote-host:/usr/share/hub-bucket/GameImages/ `

Comment: While using SSH key -> @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0644 for '/usr/share/hub-bucket/id_rsa' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
bad permissions: ignore key: /usr/share/hub-bucket/id_rsa

Comment: please check your permission

Answer (score 2):

You can use the flag `-r` to copy files recursively with scp.

```
scp -r /usr/share/hub-bucket/GameImages/ user@remotehost:/usr/share/hub-bucket/GameImages/
```

A better and often faster option is to use **rsync**, which is usually more efficient since it only transfers files that differ between the two hosts.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I haven't used SSH key for SCP, so can u given me example withh key file and also rsyc example.

Comment: `scp -i <identity file> -r <rest of options>` is all you need provided you've set up key based authentication in SSH. 

Here's a guide on how to set up key based SSH authentication: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2

`rsync -avz -e ssh sourcepath user@host:destinationpath` can be used for a similar transfer using rsync.

Comment: Thanks. so for rsync what is -avz and -e, and where is SSH key ? It's actually digital ocean to digital ocean server transfer.

Comment: -a is for archive, meaning copy everything recursively, keep all users and permissions.
-v is verbose, it displays all files being transferred. You can skip it if you wish.
-z is to enable compression of files.

The SSH key is usually located in your .ssh directory. Follow the guide in the link I posted.

And remember to use `man rsync`. ;)

Comment: I mean, where to put SSH key file. Like in scp -i <identity file>

Comment: The ssh-keygen command suggests a path, see step 2 of the guide. Then just add that path to the -i parameter, like `-i ~/.ssh/id_rsa`.

Comment: Sorry for confusion, I have SSH key but I just want to know the syntax for rsync using SSH key.

Comment: You can add ssh parameters to rsync using the syntax `rsync -av -e "ssh -i <pathtokeyfile>"`.

Comment: Thanks Janek, I will try and inform.

Comment: And like SCP, in rsync,is it possible to download file/folder from remote machine ??

Comment: Thanks u everyone.

Comment: @SudeepShakya: You're welcome. Please consider accepting the best answer.